# Equivalence of binary quadratic forms

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> I want to determine whether the following binary quadratic forms are equivalent:
> $f(x,y)=x^2+5y^2, g(x,y)=2x^2+2xy+3y^2$

I know that in order to prove $f,g$ are equivalent we need to show that there exists a matrix $A\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $g(x,y)=f((x,y)\cdot A$ but I'm not sure how to find this specific matrix or how to determine existence without finding this. Is there a straightforward way to find such a matrix or show its nonexistence?

Comment: You have written $f((x,y)\cdot A$, which suffers from unbalanced parentheses, but worse, how do you get a form by multiplying a form by a matrix? You have to understand how a group element acts on a form to make any progress on your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson you get a form by fixing the balanced parentheses: $f((x,y) \cdot A)$.  Problem solved, since it makes sense to multiply a row vector $(x \, y)$ by a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to answer the question.

One way is to use the fact that equivalent forms represent the same numbers. Now, $g$ represents $3$, but $f$ does not. Therefore, they are not equivalent.

Another way is to note that every binary quadratic form of negative discriminant is equivalent to a unique reduced form. The two forms given in your question are already reduced, so we see that they are not equivalent.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried applying this to more problems but get stumped when $f$ is in fact equivalent to $g$: for instance, $f(x,y)=x^2+xy+3y^2,g(x,y)=x^2+xy+y^2$. How would you approach this?

Comment: Why do you think these forms are equivalent?